# How to update the Gravity Form field default value

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to update the default value of a field. Currently, I have a hidden text field called 'Limit' with a default value set to 'No'. I want to change the default value to 'Yes' when the number of entries is greater or equal to  3. I use the gform_after_submission hook to call my function.

Please see my code below.

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_112', 'update_limit', 10, 2 );
function update_limit($entry, $form){
    $max_count = 3;
    $no_wait_field_id = 55;
    $entry_count = get_no_wait_count( $form['id'], $no_wait_field_id );
    if($entry_count >= $max_count){
        $no_wait_field->defaultValue = 'Yes';
        error_log("Default value set to Yes");
    }
}
function get_no_wait_count($form_id, $field_id){
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array( 'key' => $field_id , 'value' => 'No' );
    $count = GFAPI::count_entries( $form_id, $search_criteria );
    return $count;
}
```

I can see the string "Default value set to Yes" output to the terminal, but the default value is not updated in the form. Could somebody please tell me how I can fix it? Thanks.
FYI, I have another text field called Notice. This Notice field has a conditional logic. It will only be displayed if the default value of the Limit field is set to 'Yes'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaJqd.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_112', 'update_limit' );
function update_limit( $form ) {
  foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
    if( 55 === $field->id && GFAPI::count_entries( '112' >= 3 )) { 
      $field->defaultValue = 'Yes';
    }else if( $field->id == 55  && GFAPI::count_entries( $form['id'] < 3 )) { 
      $field->defaultValue = 'No';
    }
  }
  // Return the updated form
  return $form;
}
```